# Socket соединение в режиме Doze

Tags: java, android, сокет, websocket

Суть вопроса такая: Имеется клиентское приложение которое периодически отправляет клинту keep-alive. После, клиент отправляет на сервер некоторые данные. Сейчас это реализовано с помощью fcm. Но решили переработать используя свой собственный соккет сервер. В целом, fcm свои задачи по большей части выполняет, за исключением некоторых китайских смартфонов. Почитав ответы на другие вопросы с такой же проблемой, увидел что в режиме doze все сетевые процессы закрываются, несмотря на наличие запущенной службы и т д. Вопрос в том, как обеспечить целостность и гарантированность передачи данных, даже в doze mode(например как пуши телеграма или вотсапа). Не беря в расчёт интернет соединение и прочее.